# Laravel - Put all records together?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get every 'stat' value from every record in where government_type = 'higher_government' but at the moment my code only gets the stats instances for the first government role it finds, how can I put together all of the stats in some sort of array?

```
$higherGovernment = Cache::remember('government.higher_government', 1, function() {
    return GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->first()->stats;
});
```

Stats relationship:

```
public function government_role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Website\Roleplay\GovernmentRole', 'government_id');
    }
```

Government relationship:1

```
    public function stats(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'government_id');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pluck()->toArray()`

```
GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')->pluck('stats')->toArray();
```

This code will return an array of `stats` properties.

Comment: This works, but when using my blade code its foreaching the government roles, not the stats? @foreach ($juniorGovernment as $governmentMember)
                                Found an instance.<br>
                            endforeach

Comment: I don't see code related to `$juniorGovernment` in your question. What is that?

Comment: It's just another type, the same as $higherGovernment, it would happen if I used any. I have $higherGovernment, $seniorGovernment and $juniorGovernment.

Comment: I'm 100% sure my code works. It seems the problem is in using `Cache:: remember()` or something else (as we don't see whole code, we can't help you here).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `pluck()` method from Eloquent's Collection. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck

Change your query to something like:

```
GovernmentRole::where('government_type', 'higher_government')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('stats', 'government_id');
```

This will give you a collection containing `government_id` => `stats`.

If you want an array rather than a collection, simply add `->toArray()`